# Using WFS layers in Virtual Layer crashing/too slow QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, virtual-layer

I am trying to create a virtual layer with the following code, where the layers are provided by a WFS:

```
select geometry from (
select geometry from "Ancient Woodlands (England)" union all 
select geometry from "Areas of Outstanding Natural Beauty (England)" union all 
select geometry from "Country Parks" union all 
select geometry from "Flood Map for Planning (Rivers and Sea) - Flood Zone 3" union all 
select geometry from "Flood Map for Planning (Rivers and Sea) - Flood Zone 2" union all 
select geometry from "Local Nature Reserves (England)" union all 
select geometry from "National Parks (England)" union all 
select geometry from "RAMSAR (England)" union all 
select geometry from "Sites of Special Scientific Interest (England)" union all 
select geometry from "Special Areas of Conservation (England)" union all 
select geometry from "Special Protection Areas (England)" union all 
select geometry from "SSSI Unit (England)" union all 
select geometry from "World Heritage Sites" union all 
select geometry from "Registered Parks and Gardens"  union all
select geometry from "Registered Battlefields")
as Constraint_Area
```

The WFS layers are set to load only the visible extents (`restrictToRequestBBOX='1'`). The layers load quickly individually but the virtual layer takes forever causing QGIS to stop responding. Is there a way to perform this query successfully?